# Modding an exponent with a large mod

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

How can I calculate $$24^{43}\mod 85$$ with few steps? I've tried splitting it up into $$24^{43}\mod 5$$ and $$24^{43}\mod 17$$ and then solving with the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but it still requires a lot of steps. I'm wondering if there's an easier way to calculate it.

Comment: Hm, this does require a lot of steps, but I hope you can use it.
$$24^{43}\equiv(-1)^{43}\equiv-1\pmod5$$
$$24^{43}\equiv7^{43}\equiv7^9(7^2)^{17}\equiv7^97^2\equiv7\times49^5\equiv7\times(-2)^5\equiv-7\times32\equiv-14\pmod{17}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $3\cdot 85=255$ and $2^8=256\equiv 1\pmod{85}$ and $3^4=81\equiv -4\pmod{85}$ so that $$24^{43}=3^{43}\cdot 2^{3\cdot 43}=(3^4)^{10}\cdot 3^3\cdot (2^8)^{16}\cdot 2\equiv (-4)^{10}\cdot 54=(2^8)^2\cdot 2^4\cdot 54=23\cdot 8=184\equiv\boxed{14}$$
A few more steps than necesary are shown for detail, but the idea is to use $2^8\equiv 1$ as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I like how your answer was clear yet short.

Comment: No problem. Sorry it's not any shorter. I'm not sure if it's coincidence, but it seemed funny that $85-43=42$. So, I was thinking there might be some trick using this partial symmetry.